# Ignore and error and complete the code in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am now working on calculating PESQ metric for measuring the quality of speech quality, sometimes this metric cannot be computed and give an error called Processing error!. The question is I want to write an exception if the score cannot be computed pass and go to the next signal. This is a simple code I used.

```
for x, filename in enumerate(glob.glob('/home/mnabih/NoisyFSC/AY5e3mMgZkIyG3Ox/*.wav')):
    print(x, filename)
    mix, sr = sf.read(filename)  ##Why do you need this one btw, you never use it
    enhname = filename.replace('NoisyFSC', 'FSCen')
    enh, sr = sf.read(enhname)
    oriname = filename.replace('NoisyFSC', 'clean')
    ori, sr = sf.read(oriname)
    print('******************************************************************')
    pesq_en_mix.append(pesq(16000, mix, enh, 'nb'))
    pesq_ori_mix.append(pesq(16000, mix, ori, 'nb'))
    pesq_enh_ori.append(pesq(16000, ori, enh, 'nb'))
```

What I try to do is:

```
try: 
   print(pesq(16000, mix, enh, 'nb'), pesq(16000, mix,ori, 'nb'), pesq(16000, ori, enh, 'nb')) 
   if print(pesq(16000, mix, enh, 'nb'), pesq(16000, mix,ori, 'nb'), pesq(16000, ori, enh, 'nb')): raise "Proceesing error!" 
   pass 
   else: 
        print(pesq(16000, mix, enh, 'nb'), pesq(16000, mix,ori, 'nb'), pesq(16000, ori, enh, 'nb'))
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use `try` and `except` like shown here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: @Scrapper142 Can you give me a hint as I tried but  failed to write it.

Comment: @MohamedNabih What did you try? How did it fail? That tutorial covers the `try-except` construct pretty comprehensively.

Comment: ` try:
        print(pesq(16000, mix, enh, 'nb'), pesq(16000, mix,ori, 'nb'), pesq(16000, ori, enh, 'nb'))
        if print(pesq(16000, mix, enh, 'nb'), pesq(16000, mix,ori, 'nb'), pesq(16000, ori, enh, 'nb')): raise "Proceesing error!"                
        else:
          print(pesq(16000, mix, enh, 'nb'), pesq(16000, mix,ori, 'nb'), pesq(16000, ori, enh, 'nb'))
                  pesq_en_mix.append(pesq(16000, mix, enh, 'nb'))
          pesq_ori_mix.append(pesq(16000, mix, ori, 'nb'))
          pesq_enh_ori.append(pesq(16000, ori, enh, 'nb')) `

Comment: @PranavHosangadi  `   try: print(pesq(16000, mix, enh, 'nb'), pesq(16000, mix,ori, 'nb'), pesq(16000, ori, enh, 'nb')) if print(pesq(16000, mix, enh, 'nb'), pesq(16000, mix,ori, 'nb'), pesq(16000, ori, enh, 'nb')): raise "Proceesing error!"   `

Comment: [Edit] your question to add that code. It's unreadable as a comment @MohamedNabih

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Can you see the edit now

Comment: Yes. Where's the accompanying `except` clause?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Do you mean add except statment

Comment: Yes! a `try` needs an `except` to work.

Comment: I know but the exception here is that the score returns "Processing error!" message is it possible

Comment: @PranavHosangadi  I add an except statement like except "Processing error!" pass, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

say we have the function

```py
def getListElementSquared(list, index):
    return list[index] ** 2
```

Then it works in theory

```py
myList = [0, 1, 2, 3]
print(getListElementSquared(myList, 2))  # 4, since it squares from index 2 which is 2
```

But we can run into problems

```py
print(getListElementSquared(myList, 7))  # says there's an IndexError, because myList has nothing at index 7

myStringList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

print(getListElementSquared(myStringList, 2))  # says TypeError, since you it is trying to square
```

So we might want to do something in case we get one of those errors. Here's the function to handle those:

```py
def getListElementSquared(list, index):
    try:
        # everything here will try to run normally
        return list[index] ** 2
    except IndexError:
        # this will only run if the code in try raises an IndexError, see example for why this could happen
        return 'requested index does not exist'
    except TypeError:
        # this will only run if there is a type error, which happens if you try to sqaure something that is not a number
        return 'cannot square item that is not a number'
    except:
        # this will handle any error other that type or index
        return 'an unknown error occured'

# Tests
myList = [0, 1, 2, 3]
print(getListElementSquared(myList, 2))  # 4

print(getListElementSquared(myList, 7))  # 'requested index does not exist'

myStringList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
print(getListElementSquared(myStringList, 2))  # 'cannot square item that is not a number'
```

---

In your function, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. If an error is raised on one of lines, put in in a `try` block, and have an `except ProcessingError:` block. If you want to raise processing error yourself, use `raise ProcessingError`. If you want to raise it yourself but that error is not defined, first use `class ProcessingError(Exception): pass`